# Smart/Dumb Component Pattern in an Angular Scenario

Tags: angular, angular-ui

I have a “smart” parent component that collects information from the user using 2 presentation components (like a two-step wizard): the first step collecting some information about the item to purchase and the second step asking for payment information.

Consider step 2, a presentation (dumb) component that uses form controls and Stripe Elements to capture the user payment info. Ideally, this component would use an `EventEmitter` to expose the collected payment information to the parent component that would then call the server to create the purchase. (No?) However, what happens when the parent component calls Stripe’s Create Customer API for instance, and gets an error; shouldn’t the child presentation component then display this error? Would the parent communicate this error as an `@Input` to the child component via a variable? Or should the parent component rather just leave the Stripe API calling part to the child component that would only emit the event once payment information is valid and let the parent component only continue the purchasing workflow from there?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/

Comment: Thank you, I did, but this does not actually attack the specific scenario of error display.